# Batch normalization vs layer normalization

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Please illustrate batch normalisation and layer normalisation with a clear notation involving tensors. Also comment on when each one is required/recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is in *[Group Normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08494), by Yuxin Wu, Kaiming He IJCV'20*.

Especially **Fig. 2**:

[image]